# Reshape a dataframe in order to slice min / max for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe looking like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~id,  ~name,       ~type, ~value,
          1, "aaaa",       "car",   2.67,
          1, "aaaa",      "moto",      2,
          2, "bbbb",      "bike",   3.67,
          4, "cccc",     "skate",   2.75,
          6, "dddd", "snowboard",   4.33,
          7, "eeee",   "scooter",    2.8,
          7, "eeee",       "car",   2.33,
          7, "eeee",       "ski",    2.5,
          8, "ffff",      "boat",      3,
          8, "ffff",   "scooter",    2.8
        )
```

I would like to get for each `id`, `name`:

1. the best type based on the `value` aka `max(value)`
2. the worst type based on the `value` aka `min(value)`
3. whenever there is only one row for each combination of `id`/`name`, I would like the value to be placed into the `~best` column, while `-` should be appearing in the `~worst`

Resulting in:

```
df_final <- tibble::tribble(
              ~id,  ~name,       ~best,    ~worst,
                1, "aaaa",       "car",    "moto",
                2, "bbbb",      "bike",       "-",
                4, "cccc",     "skate",       "-",
                6, "dddd", "snowboard",       "-",
                7, "eeee",   "scooter",     "car",
                8, "ffff",      "boat", "scooter"
              )
```

I tried to use `slice_max()` but I can't figure out how to place the `type` in the `~best` / `~worst` columns!

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to `arrange` by `value` from highest to lowest value, and then using `summarise` take the `first` and `last` values as "best" and "worst."

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  arrange(id, name, desc(value)) %>%
  summarise(best = first(type), 
            worst = ifelse(n() == 1, "-", last(type)))
```

**Output**

```
     id name  best      worst  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
1     1 aaaa  car       moto   
2     2 bbbb  bike      -      
3     4 cccc  skate     -      
4     6 dddd  snowboard -      
5     7 eeee  scooter   car    
6     8 ffff  boat      scooter
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  summarize(best = type[value == max(value)],
            worst = type[value == min(value)],
            n = n()) %>%
  mutate(worst = if_else(n == 1, '-', worst)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [6]
     id name  best      worst  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
1     1 aaaa  car       moto   
2     2 bbbb  bike      -      
3     4 cccc  skate     -      
4     6 dddd  snowboard -      
5     7 eeee  scooter   car    
6     8 ffff  boat      scooter
```

---

Alternative solution as suggested in the comment:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  summarize(best = type[value == max(value)],
            worst = if_else(n() == 1, "-", type[value == min(value)]),
            .groups = "drop")
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id name  best      worst  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
1     1 aaaa  car       moto   
2     2 bbbb  bike      -      
3     4 cccc  skate     -      
4     6 dddd  snowboard -      
5     7 eeee  scooter   car    
6     8 ffff  boat      scooter
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts, you can eliminate the `mutate` by including the `if_else` in the `worst` calculation. You can also remove the grouping after summarize by either adding `.groups = "drop"` in the call or using `%>% ungroup()`.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions. I kept the grouping since the TO wanted to perform the calculations for a specific id/name grouping. And while the grouping isn‘t necessary anymore once the summarize command has run, I wanted to keep it for illustrative purposes. Same with the ifelse/mutate command to show the sequential approach here.